# nested x-repeat element in 0.8

Tags: polymer

is it possible to do something like:

```
         <template is="x-repeat" items="{{dataSource}}"> <!--called item-->
            <tr>
              <template is="x-repeat" items="{{columns}}"> <!--also called item-->
                <td data-title$="{{itemFromSecondRepeat.displayName}}">
                   {{}} <!--How to {{itemfromtopRepeat[itemFromSecondRepeat.name]}}-->
                </td>
              </template>
            </tr>
          </template>
```

the problem is in this x-repeat element i can't figure out how to access the items, is this a constraint by design in `0.8` or is there a way to specify the name such as `{{i in items}}` in `0.5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but only if you bind to the `item`'s sub-properties. See https://www.polymer-project.org/0.8/docs/devguide/experimental.html#x-repeat.

For example:

```
<template is="x-repeat" items="{{rows}}">
  <div>
      <span>{{item.letter}}</span>
      <template is="x-repeat" items="{{item.columns}}">
        <span>{{item.number}}</span>
      </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Where:

```
properties: {
  rows: {
    type: Array,
    value: [{
      letter: 'A',
      columns: [{number: 1}, {number: 2}]
    }, {
      letter: 'B',
      columns: [{number: 3}, {number: 4}]
    }]
  }
}
```

Produces this:

```
A 1 2
B 3 4
```

The interesting thing I found when testing this is that Polymer isn't able to bind the `{{item}}` to an attribute of a nested custom element. Instead, it seems to only work if you pass individual sub-properties of `item`.

```
<x-grid-cell color={{item.color}}></x-grid-cell> // works
```

vs.

```
<x-grid-cell cell={{item}}></x-grid-cell> // doesn't seem to work
```